# The target entry-point "@ionic-native/media-capture" has missing dependencies: - @ionic-native/core

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic-native

When I try to build my ionic mobile app on android I get the following error.

```
An error occurred during the build:
Error: The target entry-point "@ionic-native/media-capture" has missing dependencies:
 - @ionic-native/core

    at TargetedEntryPointFinder.findEntryPoints (/Users/prabhashibuddhima/Documents/Personal/Projects/VRec/myVideo/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/ngcc/src/entry_point_finder/targeted_entry_point_finder.js:40:23)
    at /Users/prabhashibuddhima/Documents/Personal/Projects/VRec/myVideo/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/ngcc/src/execution/analyze_entry_points.js:28:41
    at SingleProcessExecutorSync.SingleProcessorExecutorBase.doExecute (/Users/prabhashibuddhima/Documents/Personal/Projects/VRec/myVideo/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/ngcc/src/execution/single_process_executor.js:28:29)
    at /Users/prabhashibuddhima/Documents/Personal/Projects/VRec/myVideo/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/ngcc/src/execution/single_process_executor.js:57:59
    at SyncLocker.lock (/Users/prabhashibuddhima/Documents/Personal/Projects/VRec/myVideo/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/ngcc/src/locking/sync_locker.js:34:24)
    at SingleProcessExecutorSync.execute (/Users/prabhashibuddhima/Documents/Personal/Projects/VRec/myVideo/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/ngcc/src/execution/single_process_executor.js:57:27)
    at Object.mainNgcc (/Users/prabhashibuddhima/Documents/Personal/Projects/VRec/myVideo/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/ngcc/src/main.js:74:25)
    at Object.process (/Users/prabhashibuddhima/Documents/Personal/Projects/VRec/myVideo/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/ngcc/index.js:29:23)
    at NgccProcessor.processModule (/Users/prabhashibuddhima/Documents/Personal/Projects/VRec/myVideo/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/ngcc_processor.js:163:16)
    at /Users/prabhashibuddhima/Documents/Personal/Projects/VRec/myVideo/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/ivy/host.js:55:18
    at /Users/prabhashibuddhima/Documents/Personal/Projects/VRec/myVideo/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/ivy/host.js:47:24
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at Object.host.resolveModuleNames (/Users/prabhashibuddhima/Documents/Personal/Projects/VRec/myVideo/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/ivy/host.js:45:32)
    at actualResolveModuleNamesWorker (/Users/prabhashibuddhima/Documents/Personal/Projects/VRec/myVideo/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:102904:133)
    at resolveModuleNamesWorker (/Users/prabhashibuddhima/Documents/Personal/Projects/VRec/myVideo/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:103126:26)
    at resolveModuleNamesReusingOldState (/Users/prabhashibuddhima/Documents/Personal/Projects/VRec/myVideo/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:103200:24)
An unhandled exception occurred: The target entry-point "@ionic-native/media-capture" has missing dependencies:
 - @ionic-native/core

See "/private/var/folders/vp/8s5chkws6tx5v3wjyvr7n_qm0000gn/T/ng-HBL1kz/angular-errors.log" for further details.
```

I’m getting this error not only with the media-capture plugin. With Image-picker, file plugins also I’m getting the same error. I tried recreating the project, removing platforms and plugins and adding them again, npm install and all.

Please help me to solve this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that you miss the `@ionic-native/core` dependency.
You need to run `npm install --save @ionic-native/core` to install it.

If the problem persists, try to delete the `node_modules` folder, and run `npm install` again.

Comment: This works!! for all An unhandled exception occurred: The target entry-point "@ionic-native/<plugin-name>" has missing dependencies:
[ng]  - @ionic-native/core though delete the node_modules folder is optional.

Answer (score 0):

the error means that  you have installed  `@ionic-native/media-capture` but it is lacking   `@ionic-native/core` dependence which you need to install

by running this command:

`npm i  @ionic-native/core --save`